# LWUIT : Image as Background in Form

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have started using LWUIT which sounds interesting , i have made a form and has simply added an image to its background , my problem is that the image is getting streched and looks bad :D
is there any way to set an image not to get stretshd on a form or any other component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the version of LWUIT you are using. In 1.4 you could define `bgType` in the  Style to be BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ALIGNED and then define the `bgAlign` value to whatever you want (there are many types/alignments).

The latest SVN and upcoming 1.5 simplifies this by removing bgAlign and adding to bgType all the alignment/tiling possibilities e.g. `BACKGROUND_IMAGE_TILE_VERTICAL_ALIGN_RIGHT` or `BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ALIGNED_TOP_LEFT` etc...

You can edit all of these visually in the resource editor using the theme.

Comment: thank you very much for this reply..im using 1.4 version of LWUIT and tried using bgType but it does not show my image...this is my code...kindly look into matter and let me know my mistake..regards

Comment: private byte BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ALIGN_RIGHT ;
public void startApp() {
    Display.init(this);
 Form main=new Form();
main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        try {
 Image image1 = Image.createImage("/progress0.png");
main.getStyle().setBgImage(image1);
main.getStyle().setBackgroundType(BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ALIGN_RIGHT);
               } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
main.show();

Comment: i replaced this line : main.getStyle().setBackgroundType(BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ALIGN_RIGHT with main.getStyle().setBackgroundAlignment(BACKGROUND_ALIGNMENT);
but still getting the same result for every type , the image is getting stretched filling the screen, how can i sole this problem??

Comment: Invoke setBackgroundType(BACKGROUND_ALIGNMENT) then for setBackgroundAlignment use BACKGROUND_IMAGE_ALIGN_RIGHT. This is all in the javadoc for these methods.